# evaluating integral over surface of the sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

This is what I've tried. Am I approaching this the right way? Also, where do I go next?

[image]

Comment: Looks good so far. The inner antiderivative suggests $u=\cos \theta$ and that's good since then $du=-\sin \theta$ and you have the $\sin \theta$ where it's needed.

Comment: Há um erro: exp(a*cos(x)) != exp(a)*exp(cos(x))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the next steps are the following:
$$\begin{matrix}
\iint_Se^z\,dS&=&\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}e^{a\,\cos\theta}a^2\sin\theta\,d\theta d\phi\\
              &=&a^2e^a\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{\cos\theta}\sin\theta\,d\theta d\phi \\
&=&2\pi a^2e^a\int_0^\pi d(-e^{\cos\theta})\\
&=&2\pi a^2e^a\left(e-\frac{1}{e}\right)
\end{matrix}$$